# position div at top-left corner of image using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a rich-text editor and I am trying to place a delete button div at top-left corner of an image dynamically inserted by javascript. Thus I must determine the position of the div at run-time. However, I couldn't make it exactly located at the top-left corner. Here is my code:

```
function showDeleteButton(image) {
    var rect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
    var top = rect.top + $(document).scrollTop();
    var left = rect.left + $(document).scrollLeft();
    var deleteButton = $(".delete_button")[0];
    deleteButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
    deleteButton.style.top = top + "px";
    deleteButton.style.left = left + "px";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what you're looking for is offset in jquery

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div>
    <div id="delete_button"></div>
    <img src"foo.png" />
</div>
```

and css

```
#delete_button{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place the delete button as a direct child of `body` element. Then you can measure the offset of an hovered image and reposition the button to its top left corner.

CSS

```css
.delete_button {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```js
$(function() {
    var deleteButton = $(".delete_button");
    var hovered_image = false;
    $('img').mouseenter(function(e) {
        hovered_image = this;
        deleteButton.show();
        var img = $(this);
        var offset = img.offset();
        deleteButton.css({
            top: offset.top + 'px',
            left: offset.left + 'px'
        });
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        if (e.relatedTarget === deleteButton[0]) {
            return;
        }
        deleteButton.hide();
        hovered_image = false;
    });
    deleteButton.mouseleave(function(e){
        if (e.relatedTarget === hovered_image) {
            return;
        }
        deleteButton.hide();
        hovered_image = false;
    });
    deleteButton.click(function(e){
        hovered_image.parentNode.removeChild(hovered_image);
        deleteButton.hide();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djuVT/  -the above solution with jQuery's [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method and `position:absolute`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djuVT/1/ -alternative solution with Javascript's [.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) method and `position:fixed;` CSS

Comment: somehow the deleteButton.show() doesn't work...but I figured out another way to do it. Thanks